# Document generation library

Tags: pdf, document-converter

I need advice about a technical problem regarding to document generation (PDF, Doc). I want to provide external data and combine that with a predefined template. The goal is to generate a lot of different kind of documents (invoices, information pages, etc..)

Is there a solution that already exists? That works with a flexible template format and can be easily combined with external data like Json/XML. The language does not really matter as long it can be uses in a Saas environment.

Thx.

Comment: Sounds like you want a HTML to PDF converter. HTML is arguably the most powerful layout engine out there, so just need to find a HTML to PDF converter. Using HTML as your engine ensures you don't end up in any vendor lock in.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bytescout PDF Generator SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfsdk/index.html) can successfully create PDF and Docx documents from an HTML source and it offers plenty of customization and fine tuning.

Please check out the following samples:

- [How to convert HTML to PDF in C# and ByteScout PDF SDK](https://github.com/bytescout/pdf-sdk-samples/tree/master/C%23/Convert%20HTML%20to%20PDF)
- [How to convert HTML to DOCX in C# and ByteScout PDF SDK](https://github.com/bytescout/pdf-sdk-samples/tree/master/C%23/Convert%20HTML%20to%20DOCX)

*Disclaimer: I work for Bytescout.*

Answer (score 0):

A templating engine such as [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/) or [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) allows you to define your own document template and then substitute in data.  The templates could be used to produce HTML or Markdown that could be converted to PDF using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for converting HTML to PDF as recommended, consider using [ePrint](https://eprintdriver.com/).  This is an end-user product which can convert to and from multiple different file formats, save, print, email and consolidate files.  There's more information on the [official site](https://eprintdriver.com/) and [an evaluation](https://eprintdriver.com/Download) is available as well.

Disclaimer:  I work for the company that makes this product.